# Matlab copy all images to another file in different names

Tags: image, matlab, copy, rename

I want to copy all images in a file to another file with different names. But, images order changes during copy. For example, this order like that: B0. jpg,B1.jpg,..,B9.jpg,B10.jpg,B11.jpg..,B30.jpg. I want to change the name of B0.jpg to image1.jpg, B1.jpg to image2.jpg in a similar. But, it changes B0.jpg to B10.jpg and then B11.jpg instead of B1,B2,B3...Because of that images order changed. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the SO orders the file names using ASCII sorting, as they're strings (it doesn't look to numbers differently). The string "10" is placed before the string "2", because "1" < "2".

Instead of relying on the order, you could do something like this:

```
imgs = dir('*.jpg');
for i = 1:numel(imgs)
    % Change the 'B' to 'image'
    newName = strrep(imgs(i).name, 'B', 'image');

    % Copy the image
    copyfile(imgs(i).name, ['c:\destination\' newName]);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This solves the problem when images name is only B. I gave B as an example.  Images name can be different or irregular like a_360,x-180.jpg or B0.jpg . Is there any solution to get the names of images with true order that starts at file's first element to get name, and then second until the last element(image)?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add all the details relevant to the solution. If there are more cases than 'B[number].jpg', put them all on the description so people are more able to help giving you an acceptable solution.